# Make WCF webservice available over http and https using basicHttpsBinding

Tags: web-services, wcf, http, https

I'm trying to make my webservice available over http and https, but I'm running into this error:

`A child element named 'endpoint' with same key already exists at the same configuration scope. Collection elements must be unique within the same configuration scope (e.g. the same application.config file). Duplicate key value:  'address:;bindingConfiguration;bindingName:;bindingNamespace:;bindingSectionName:basicHttpsBinding;contractType:RestService.Iservice;kind:;endpointConfiguration:;'.`

Now, that's a clear error, but I don't know how to alter my configuration to support http and https requests on the same contract.
Notice that I wish to use the WCF4.5 `basicHttpsBinding` configuration.

Here's my configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.service">
<!--
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://www.nl/service.svc/" />
            <add baseAddress = "https://www.nl/service.svc/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>       
-->
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" address="" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" name="RestService.Iservice" contract="RestService.Iservice">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" address="" name="RestService.Iservice" contract="RestService.Iservice">    
        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpsBindingWithJsonP">
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your endpoints, you need to set the binding of the Json endpoints to webHttpBinding, not basicHttpBinding. For the secured endpoint, you'll need to add a binding configuration and set the security mode to transport.

Also, please set an address for either the web/basic endpoint. I'm pretty sure you cannot use those two bindings with the same address.

Lastly, since you are hosted under IIS, you can remove the baseAddress section as it is not required. And make sure your web site in IIS is configured to support the http and https protocols (check that through the web site's bindings dialog in the IIS Manager)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've completed your suggestions 1 and 3 (updated my post based on your suggestions). But not sure how to do your 2nd suggestion: "please set an address for either the web/basic endpoint"
I want the service to be available over http and https...any example how I would do it?